SVG package and \AddToHook
I've just noticed a weird behavior of the SVG package when combined with Hook. If I run the following code, which just write a simple text to each page of a document
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{shipout}{abc}
\begin{document}
page 1
\newpage
page 2
\end{document}

the generated pdf (with pdflatex, MacTeX 2024) contains 2 pages with the desired output.
However, if I run now this code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\AddToHook{shipout}{abc}
\begin{document}
page 1
\newpage
page 2
\end{document}

the generated pdf has now 3 pages (!?), the last one with only the appended text "abc".
The doc of the package SVG mentions a bug with the package "lastpage" but nothing about hooks in general.
Does anybody know how to solve this issue?
I tried some of the svg options such as "lastpage=true" without any effect.

well the pgf packages does something at end document to add pdf resources. But generally: do not put typesetting material in this hook.

I see. Do you know any clean way to add typesetting material at the beginning of each page?

perhaps the afterpage package, but it is rather unclear what you want to add. In any case you need to be careful if you mess around with the shipout or the output routine.

You can add material to be typeset overlaying or underlaying the content of the page in the shipout/background or shipout/foreground hooks.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(\oddsidemargin,-\topmargin){abc}}
\begin{document}
  page 1
  \newpage
  page 2
\end{document}


Thank you. I know this solution but somehow it doesn't match my need as I want the appended text to coexist with the text of the page

@LaurentJacques Could you explain a bit more? I take it this is not for a header or footer, so where exactly are you trying to add the text? There are other hooks you can use, but it is a bit tricky without more idea of your goal. background or foreground is a reasonable guess in most cases, but if it isn't right for your case, further guesses are  likely to be fruitless.

Thank you. I tried to play a lot with "fancyhdr" to add different headers on odd and even pages. Somehow, the solution proposed by fancyhdr doesn't work for me as I want (i) odd and even header with different height, (ii) I want the top of these headers to always be a the same distance from the top of the page, the text starting right below them. That's why I started to play with  \AddToHook -- but this is maybe not the best idea -- to append these headers right before any text starting at each page. Fancyhdr doesn't allow me to do this and is generally a mess for variable height headers.

@LaurentJacques That is not what fancyhdr is designed to do. It handles the headers and footers. It doesn't handle the page layout, which includes where the headers and footers go. The most it will do is issue a warning if the space allowed for the header is too small. So does the height of the text block differ on different pages? I suggest asking a new question about how to do what you want to do. It may be that a workaround is better than a direct solution e.g. adding negative vertical space on odd (or even) pages rather than changing the actual layout - I'm not sure.
